# Why does the console give wrong output, when I've written the code without mistake in python?

Tags: python

#I've written a code, which should check the age of the user (Not allowed ages: 1-17). My problem is that when I run it, it shows at every number ("Welcome"), even 1-17. I think the problem is in the if-statement somewhere. The code should run like: if the user is underaged(1-17), print("You're not allowed to enter"). Else (above 17) print("Welcome").

```
 #My code:

print("Hello, please enter your name:" )

name = input()

print("enter your age please: ")

age = int(input())
age_restriction = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17

if age != age_restriction:
    print("Welcome")
else:
    print ("Your not allowed to enter")
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Also, think about what `age != age_restriction` is actually checking. Do you really want to check if the number is equal to a whole tuple of numbers?

Comment: Yes, or reversed: if age == age_restriction: print("You're not allowed to enter") else: print("Welcome")

Comment: No. You don't want to check if the number is *equal* to the list, you want to check if it's *in* the list. There's a difference. See Barmar's answer. `1 == [1, 2, 3]` will never be true.

Comment: @TheProgrammerGuy You missed the point `Carcigenicate` is making: a scalar integer can *never* be equal to a tuple.  They're not of the same type, are not compatible dimension, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an age_restriction variable wherein you list all restricted ages won't it be better to just do it like this?

```
if age > 17:
  print("Welcome")
else:
  print("You're not allowed to enter")
```

Comment: `17` should probably be a variable, e.g. `mininum_age`.

Comment: Oh yeah correct, sorry I forgot to put 17 inside a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `in/not in` operator to test if something is in a tuple, not `==/!=`.

```
if age not in age_restriction:
    print("Welcome")
else:
    print("You're not allowed to enter")
```

Comment: Indeed, I didn't know that, because I'm new here and at Python.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem more directly, you have to use the python `in` operator, like so:

```
if age in age_restriction:
    print ("Your not allowed to enter")
else:
    print("Welcome")
```

As Pablo said though, it would be much better practice to check if that number is less than **18**

Answer (score 1):

Your condition `age != age_restrictions` is comparing a single number with a tuple of numbers. What you can do is use `if age not in age_restrictions`: that will check whether the number `age` is contained within the tuple `age_restrictions`.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you the wrong result because `age` is not a tuple, but a number. on the other hand `age_restriction` is a tuple of multiple integers and therefore `age` will never be equals to `age_restirctions` variable.

You could use **object** `not` `in` **tuple**

```
age_restriction = range(0, 17);

if age not in age_restriction:
    print("Welcome")
else:
    print ("You're not allowed to enter")
```

or simply set age_restriction variable to 18 and have the following

```
age_restriction = 18;

if age >= age_restriction:
    print("Welcome")
else:
    print ("You're not allowed to enter")
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. There's no point in making a list with ages restriction since they are just all the natural numbers up to 17.

```
print("Hello, please enter your name:" )

name = input()

print("enter your age please: ")

age = int(input())

if (age>17):

    print("Welcome")

else:

    print ("Your not allowed to enter")
```